# How to rotate sprite image in 360 degree view in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

But the problem is iam not able to rotate the sprite image based on user interaction.for eg: when the user moves the mouse on right the frame on right side should moved and when the user moves on left the left side of the frames should me moved iam not able to implement this in fabric js. What i have done is just rotating the sprite image onmouse move.Expected output i want is like this :https://codyhouse.co/demo/360-degrees-product-viewer/index.html

```js
var URL = 'https://codyhouse.co/demo/360-degrees-product-viewer/img/alfa.png';
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var positions = {
  topSteps: 1,
  leftSteps: 16
};
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var topStep;
var leftStep;
canWalk(URL, positions);
function canWalk(URL, positions) {
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = URL;
  //var mDown = false;      
  //onloadevent
  myImage.onload = function () {
    topStep = myImage.naturalHeight / positions.topSteps;
    leftStep = myImage.naturalWidth / positions.leftSteps;
    var docCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    docCanvas.height = topStep;
    docCanvas.width = leftStep;
    fabricImageFromURL(x, y);
  };
}
//mouseevents 
canvas.on('mouse:out', function (event) {
  console.log("mouseout")
  /*  x=0;
  y=0;
  fabricImageFromURL(x,y);*/
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (event) {
  resetvalue();
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('value of x in start', x)
    console.log('positions.leftSteps', positions.leftSteps)
    if (x == positions.leftSteps) {

      y = 1;
      fabricImageFromURL(-y * topStep, -x * leftStep)
    }
    else {

      fabricImageFromURL(-y * topStep, -x * leftStep)
      if (x < positions.leftSteps) {
        x++;
      }

    }

  }, 50);

});

function resetvalue() {
  if (x == positions.leftSteps) {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    console.log("x and y value reset to0")
  }

}
function fabricImageFromURL(top, left) {
  console.log('fabricImageFromURL value', top, left);
  fabric.Image.fromURL(URL, function (oImg) {
    oImg.set('left', left).set('top', top);
    oImg.hasControls = false;
    oImg.hasBorders = false;
    oImg.selectable = false;
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
  }, { "left": 0, "top": 0, "scaleX": 1, "scaleY": 1 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Durga can u pls help me out in this.I want this rotation based on user interaction.

Comment: I will check, try something => if you click and moves towards left/right get it the events from mouse move on canvas and calculate the direction and apply it to image that much left, like you are doing now. And no need to load the same image all the time. Use `fabric.Image.fromURL` only once to load the image.

Comment: how to combine both hold and drag event.i mean mouse down and mouse move event.

Comment: @Durga https://codyhouse.co/demo/360-degrees-product-viewer/index.html. look@dis example the same i want to be implemented in fabric js. Im struggling to implement that logic.

Comment: @Durga have u found out dat solution.I am new to fabric js so cant able figure out a new solution.

Comment: Could anybody pls help me out with this code....

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/duara8L5/), need to right the logic for the rotation.

Comment: @Durga check out this fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/iamzaidsheriff/uczrc2nn/1/)    
its working fine but the problem is it is rotating fast....how can we slow down the rotation and one more issue when the frame reaches to its last frame the top left corner  of the image gets cutout....i dnt no wats  wrong in this could u pls check and rectify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are not changing top value, no need to set top value all the time, just set left value for the image. `pixelToSkip` is the difference between mousemove pixel to call the function, if mouse move difference is less than that , then it wont call.

```js
var URL = 'https://codyhouse.co/demo/360-degrees-product-viewer/img/alfa.png';
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    selection: false
  }),
  imgObject;
var positions = {
  topSteps: 1,
  leftSteps: 16
};
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var topStep;
var leftStep;
var isMouseDown = false;
var imgObject, pixelToSkip = 10;
var clickedPointer, currPointer, diff;
canWalk(URL, positions);

function canWalk(URL, positions) {
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = URL;
  //var mDown = false;      
  //onloadevent
  myImage.onload = function() {
    topStep = myImage.naturalHeight / positions.topSteps;
    leftStep = myImage.naturalWidth / positions.leftSteps;
    canvas.setDimensions({
    height : topStep,
    width : leftStep
    })
    fabricImageFromURL(x, y);
  };
}
//mouseevents 
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(event) {
  isMouseDown = true;
  prevPointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

})
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(event) {
  //console.log("mouseout")
  /*  x=0;
  y=0;
  fabricImageFromURL(x,y);*/
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(event) {
  if (!isMouseDown) return;
  currPointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
  diff = currPointer.x - prevPointer.x;
  
  if (diff < -pixelToSkip) {

    if (x == positions.leftSteps) {
      x = 0;
    }
    
    fabricImageFromURL(-x * leftStep)
    x++;

    prevPointer = currPointer;
  } else if(diff > pixelToSkip){
    if (x == 0) {
      x = positions.leftSteps;
    }
    
    x--;
    fabricImageFromURL(-x * leftStep)
    
    prevPointer = currPointer;
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(event) {
  isMouseDown = false;
})

function fabricImageFromURL(left) {
  if (!imgObject) return
  imgObject.set('left', left);
  canvas.renderAll();
}

fabric.Image.fromURL(URL, function(oImg) {
  imgObject = oImg;
  oImg.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: false,
    selectable: false
  });
  canvas.add(oImg);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @zaid Nah because of objectCaching, it's create another cache canvas, while moving I am not creating cache of it. if you want, you can remove  objectCaching.

Comment: @zaid observed, not getting what might b a problem.

Comment: @zaid  its because canvas width and height was not correct. or else you can use like [sprite class](http://fabricjs.com/animated-sprite) , here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/rkcy7pu3/2/), download the image and run the files as cors issue fiddle not working.

Comment: @zaid copy that fiddle code to local, download that car image to same folder, run via local server, the error comes cause of cors issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165285/discussion-between-durga-and-zaid).

Comment: there is a small issue with this code...u just closely observe when we drag the image left and suddenly right there is a jerk in the image(**the image goes to left and then oly to right**).Can u pls rectify it....just  run the code snippet of the code which u have posted....u ll no wats d issue which im tryng to say

Comment: How can we apply color to this sprite image.....when we rotate this sprite image the color should be applied to all the views this car....can u pls help me ... i have searched fabric documentation but couldnt find any solution....

Comment: How can we apply color to this sprite image.....when we rotate this sprite image the color should be applied to all the views this car....can u pls help me ... i have searched fabric documentation but couldnt find any solution..
And how to particular apply color  to the tyre of the car...Im strucked...can u help me out

Comment: @zaid If the part(car) is a different object then you can change the color, As that is a whole image, I have no much idea how you can achieve that using farbricjs.

Comment: How can we add text to this sprite image.....if we rotate this car the text should be applied to all the views of the car(the text should be present in all the views of the car).can u pls help....

Comment: @zaid see what you are looking for is [clara](https://clara.io/), explore for more.

Comment: yeah dis is wat i want but  dats too complicated....its kind of cad/cam stuff...dealing with vectors and all.cant we achieve dat with fabric js.....just i want image rotation,color changing and applying text to image

Comment: a small help how to rotate text in 360 degree just the text i want to rotate in 360 degree.....just help me out in dis.....ill figure out the logic for combing both car as welll text...u just help me out in text